# How to make sure user select specific folder and remove file extension from files in the selected folder?

Tags: c#, winforms

What I have here is the user select a folder full of .txt files from a external drive and a dummy file is made with the filename to a local folder.

I have 2 questions regarding the code below.

1. How do I verify that the user select a specific folder?
2. How do I remove the .txt extension? The code copies the file name and creates the files but its labeled "text.txt.png" but I need it to read "text.png".

   ```
       int g;

       private void folderSelect()
       {
           FolderBrowserDialog folder = new FolderBrowserDialog();
           folder.RootFolder = Environment.SpecialFolder.MyComputer;
           folder.ShowNewFolderButton = false;
           folder.Description = "Select Folder";

           if (folder.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
           {
               DirectoryInfo files = new DirectoryInfo(folder.SelectedPath);
               FileInfo[] textFiles = files.GetFiles("*.txt");

               while (g < textFiles.Length)
               {

                   if (g <= textFiles.Length)
                   {
                       File.Create("path/" + (textFiles[g].Name + ".png"));
                       g++;
                   }
                   else
                   {
                       break;
                   }
               }

           }
   ```

Note: I tried using Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension to remove the extension but Im not sure if i was using it correctly.

Any help would be appreciated. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
const string NEW_PATH = "path/";
if (!Directory.Exists(NEW_PATH))
    Directory.CreateDirectory(NEW_PATH);
const string PATH_TO_CHECK = "correctpath";

FolderBrowserDialog folder = new FolderBrowserDialog();
folder.RootFolder = Environment.SpecialFolder.MyComputer;
folder.ShowNewFolderButton = false;
folder.Description = "Select Folder";

if (folder.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
{
    string pathPastDrive = folder.SelectedPath.Substring(Path.GetPathRoot(folder.SelectedPath).Length).ToLower();
    // Here it depends on whether you want to check (1) that the path is EXACTLY what you want,
    // or (2) whether the selected path just needs to END in the path that you want.
    /*1*/ if (!pathPastDrive == PATH_TO_CHECK)
    /*2*/ if (!pathPastDrive.EndsWith(PATH_TO_CHECK))
        return; // or you can throw an exception if you want

    foreach (string textFile in Directory.GetFiles(folder.SelectedPath, "*.txt"))
        File.Create(NEW_PATH + Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(textFile) + ".png");
}
```

You can use `GetFileNameWithoutExtension`, and it makes it pretty easy.

Also, if you're already sure that your new folder exists, then you can elide the first three lines and replace `NEW_PATH` with `"path/"` in the last line.

Comment: Thank you for your time but this didnt work out for me.

Comment: @Bigg_aye How so? I'd like to know so that I can fix my answer. (Especially as it worked for me.)

Comment: For some reason it never created the dummy files in the existing folder. The folder is an existing folder so i knew the path name so I removed the first three lines and replaced NEW_PATH with "path/" in the last line as you recommended.

Comment: @Bigg_aye Also, seeing as I accidentally ignored your first question, I just answered it. Check out my answer again now.

Comment: Your answer is relatively the same as Equalsk's answer when it comes to creating the file without the extension . Since you came first ill give you the credit. Is it possible if you can answer my 1st question?

Comment: @Bigg_aye I believe I did answer your first question, so If I did not, please tell me what you want me to clarify. In my code, it does make sure that the selected path is a specific path that you're looking for, no matter which drive it's on.

Comment: Yeah I had to refresh so disregard the last question in my last comment. Im checking it now.

Comment: In string pathPastDrive = path.Substring(Path.GetPathRoot(path).Length).ToLower(); What is 'path.Substring' and '(path)' referring too?

Comment: @Bigg_aye Oh oops, `path` was supposed to be `folder.SelectedPath`. It's just that I wrote this section separately.

Comment: @Bigg_aye That's what I'm here for. Good luck with your project here!

Answer (score 2):

To see the returned path just use the `SelectedPath` property, then you can compare it to whatever you had in mind. The `@` before the path just means I don't have to escape any characters, it's the same as `"C:\\MyPath"`.

```
FolderBrowserDialog folder = new FolderBrowserDialog();
if (folder.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
{
    if (folder.SelectedPath == @"C:\MyPath")
    {
        // DO SOMETHING
    }
}
```

You already hit the nail on the head about the file name without extension, change this line:

```
File.Create("path/" + (textFiles[g].Name + ".png"));
```

To this:

```
File.Create("path/" + (Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(textFiles[g].Name) + ".png"));
```

Edit:

To get the folder name you already have the DirectoryInfo object so just use that:

```
DirectoryInfo files = new DirectoryInfo(folder.SelectedPath);
string folderName = files.Name;
```

Comment: I appreciate it. You answered my 2nd question but the 1st question is in regards to a external drive so when a user plugs in a usb drive I cant predict what drive will be mapped to the usb drive. Is there a way to just verify the folder name as it has to be the same folder name always regardless of what drive the usb is mapped to?

Comment: If I've understood you right you can get the folder name from the DirectoryInfo object you already have. Updated answer.